# "Gap" between the $x_i$ when it comes to maximizing $x^TAx$ over simplex for blockwise matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

We consider the local maximizer $x^TAx$ over simplex.

$A$ is a symmetric $N \times N$  matrix with 4 blocks.

- First block $L \times L$ with elements $0 <a_{ij}<0.5$
- Second block $K \times K$ with elements $0 <a_{ij}<0.5$
- Third block $L \times K$ with elements $0.5<a_{ij}<1$
- Fourth block $K \times L$ with elements $0.5<a_{ij}<1$

except for diagonal elements that are zero, $a_{ii}=0$ for $1\leq i \leq N$. Note $L+K=N$.

Can we prove that there is a gap, meaning a margin or difference, between the first $L$ elements of $x_i$: for $1\leq i \leq L$ AND the rest of elements ($K$ elements) $x_i$ for $L< i \leq L+K=N$. Can we quantify this gap?

Comment: Where exactly do the blocks line up within $A$? You've given us enough information to **guess**, but this should really be made explicit. It sounds like
$$
A = \pmatrix{A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_{22}},
$$
with $A_{11}$ of size $L \times L$ and $A_{22}$ of size $K \times K$, with $0 < A_{11} , A_{22}< 0.5$ (not including the diagonal entries, which are zero) and $0.5 < A_{12} = A_{21}^T < 1$. Is that correct?

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, correct, except that $A_{1,1}, A_{2,2} >0.5$ and $A_{1,2}, A_{2,1}^T <0.5$.